# Is .net framework 3.5 enough to run crystal report (.rpt file)

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Just a quickie

Do i need to install crystal report full version to run my crystal report using .net application.

Or Just the .net framework 3.5 should be enough to view the reports

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5 version of the Framework is sufficient. However, you will need the Crystal viewer control to view any Crystal report (assuming you are displaying Crystal reports to a user via a WinForms).

Comment: u mean the crystal viewer that comes with framwork right. So that means i don't have to purchase anything????

Comment: Yes, the Crystal viewer that comes with the framework will work.

Comment: I don't think crystal reports viewer comes with the framework; what version of CR are you using?

Comment: Also what version of visual studio?